# Products not getting categorized under different collection items

Tags: commerce

We are developing an e-commerce site for selling of different products like earphones, music cds, musical instruments, storage devices like hard disks etc. But the problem is that if we click on earphones tab then as expected only earphones should appear but we are getting images of musical instruments, storage devices also. This is happening for other tabs also. So, basically the products are not getting categorized. Any solution??

Comment: If my understanding will be right means, you can achieve it by using taxonomy terms.

Comment: For the variation types that I have created there is no option like field_collection in add existing field. How to fix that?

Comment: You need to add Product Display types with a Product reference to the variation types. Then you display your Product Displays on a view that filters by the category on the Product Display.